# using the firefox download video addon, some video site isn't letting me downlaod the video?

Tags: firefox, video, download

I am using the firefox download helper, and I am viewing a video on a site and it doesn't seem to be letting me download the video.

the site is using a flash player, and is streaming the video. (flowplayer).

Is there a setting I have to tweak?

it works on utube.

Comment: If you are in Linux, Flash videos always get saved to the temp folder (usually /tmp) with a Flashxxxx name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the site's owners found a way to disable your download helper.